# sync data from an Active Directory database to Salesforce for single signon

Tags: apex, community

I trying to create a single sign-on for our website customer portal, so that a customer may access both restricted website information and the Salesforce self-service user portal

I have some query, please help me on this:

1. Can we use information from Active Directory to fill in a field in Salesforce?
2. Can Salesforce self-service user passwords be set or reset by us, according to Active Directory?

Please share the helpful doc/stuff/url.

Comment: Not sure if this link helps at all but in case it does... https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com_and_Microsoft_Active_Directory_Federation_Services